# Mark Radio Button as Selected ASP.NET MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page written using some fake data in my controller, to render some mock data in my view. Here is the code I have:

**Model**

**Data View Model**

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Is this a remix?")]
    public bool IsRemix { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Does this song contain sample(s)?")]
    public bool ContainsSample { get; set; }
```

**I had this in my ViewModel**

```
public bool IsRemix { get; set; }
public bool ContainsSample { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
model.Songs = songs;
model.SongTitle = "Darkside of the Moon";
model.AlternativeSongTitle = "Wish You Were Here";
model.DurationMinutes = 3;
model.DurationSeconds = 57;
model.IsRemix = true;
model.ContainsSample = false;
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4 pull-left" for="SongTitle">Is a Remix</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <label for="IsRemixYes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <label for="IsRemixNo">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4 pull-left" for="SongTitle">Contains Sample</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ContainsSample, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <label for="ContainsSampleYes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ContainsSample, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <label for="ContainsSampleNo">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am unsure how to get the radio buttons to be pre-selected.

Comment: Are there any reasons you are not using asp.net mvc Html extensions?

Comment: You bind to your model - `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix. true, new { ... })` (ditto for `false`) - and the correct button will be selected based on the value of the property

Comment: I have changed my Model and Controller slightly, I have updated it in my code above.

Comment: You can also do this if you dont want to use extension methods. `<input type="radio" id="IsRemixNo" @(IsRemix ? "checked" : "") class="dropdownNo" name="IsRemix" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: IsRemix">`

Comment: @ngeksyo I have it working on the input using:

`@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })`

Is there a way I can get it so that it uses the value from the model?

Comment: What do you mean by  `it uses the value from the model`?

Comment: So it shows the value from here: `model.IsRemix = true;
model.ContainsSample = false;`

Comment: It does use the value from the model! If the value of `IsRemix` is `true`, then the first button will be selected otherwise the 2nd will be (assuming of course that you actually passed a model to the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke There is a model passed to the view. It used the View Model which currently uses:

`public bool IsRemix { get; set; }
public bool ContainsSample { get; set; }`

I have updated my view to what I have now.

Comment: Which will work fine and correctly bind to your model properties (and the correct button will be selected).

Comment: @StephenMuecke That is working correctly now. Thanks both for your help.